# Can alligator clips be soldered to PCB pads?

Tags: pcb, connector, coax

I have a coaxial Teflon wire that is carry some high voltage signal. I do not want to solder it directly to the PCB pad as there can be issue of short circuit as there are components placed nearby the HV pad.

My plan is to solder an alligator clip to the pad, and safely solder the coax cable to the alligator clip's non-clip end and insulate the part that the user will touch. Is this a good option, or is there a safer/better alternative?

Comment: "*PCB pad as there can be issue of short circuit as there are components placed nearby the HV pad.*" Maybe you should change your layout to deal with this problem first.

Comment: The layout is fine power wise. There are 12 layers of PCB, so there will not be issue internally. The pads are about few mms off, so there is no near contact in given layout, but if a HV cable is soldered to the pad, it can cause nearby arcing at high voltages.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the PCB to me.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/turret-terminals-keystone-electronics/23324 designed to do *exact what you want

Comment: Yes thanks Lorenzo. I have used turrets in the past and did not think of using it in this use case. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. But just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Instead, use a PCB terminal and a wire terminal. There are many options, but one I recommend is:

- A [screw terminal](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=terminals_disconnects&u=board_terminals&o=board_screw_terminals&f=th_screw_terminals) on the PCB
- A [ring terminal](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=terminals_disconnects&u=wire_terminals&o=tongue_crimp_terminals&f=ring_terminals) on the wire

[Disclosure: I maintain that site]

Comment: connectorbook is a nice site. Thanks for the screw terminal and ring terminal options.